# Android Service interaction with other application

Tags: android, android-service

I was thinking if an android service could interact with other applicaitons, instead of activities of the same app. Is that possible? if yes then how to allow access to a service from other applications?

Answer (score 2):

First set up an `<intent-filter>` for your `<service>` with an `<action>` string.

Then use that action string for the Intent you use with bindService() (e.g., `new Intent("this.is.my.custom.ACTION")`)

Example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/AndroidManifest.xml).